# Android - "Application not installed" - cannot update with new apk - React Native

Tags: android, google-play, apk, react-native

I currently have React Native application in Play store. Steps done month ago:

- 1. I generated private signing key using keytool
  2. I generated kestore named prod.keystore (remembered alias)
  3. Placed my prod.keystore in android/app directory
  4. Edited ~/.gradle/gradle.properties with the correct keystore password, alias and key
  5. Edited the file android/app/build.gradle to add the signing config
  6. Ran cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease to get apk Succesfully uploaded apk to Play store

Today after some changes in my code, I generated new apk using the SAME prod.keystore(with the same keystore password, alias and key). Before that I increased android versionCode in Androidmanifest.xml and build.gradle.

I had the old version of application that I installed from Playstore. After generating new apk I tried to installed it to my phone. I expected that update will be done but after trying to install, I got the message "Application not installed". 
`adb install new-apk-name.apk` gives me little more detailed error INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE

I don't want to uninstall the app and install it again. I want to be able to update the app and test that before I upload to store. Anybody has idea why this is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution

1. Uninstall app that was downloaded from Play Store
2. Install your new apk

#### Double Check That Update Will Work For Users

> Use the following checklist to make sure your new APK is ready to update your existing users:
>
> The package name of the updated APK needs to be the same as the current version.
>   The version code needs to be greater than that current version. Learn more about versioning your applications.
>   The updated APK needs to be signed with the same signature as the current version.
>   To verify that your APK is using the same certification as the previous version, you can run the following command on both APKs and compare the results:
>
> ```
> $ jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs my_application.apk
> ```
>
> If the results are identical, you’re using the same key and are ready to continue. If the results are different, you will need to re-sign the APK with the correct key.

For more info, check Google's docs [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en)

Comment: I don't want to do that. That works. I want to make sure update will work when user download the new version of app from the play store.

Comment: Google handles that for you. If want to double check follow Google's instructions [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en)

Comment: jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs my_application.apk showed me difference in my certificates. Google play seemed to add additional signing. After uploading to store update worked!